# performance tuning sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlperformance

I have this query which is candidate for a performance tuning as it is taking for than 4-5 hours to run.

```
explain plan for SELECT /*+ PARALLEL_INDEX(ssp, sub_svc_parm_ix2, 4) 
                          INDEX(ssp sub_svc_parm_ix2) */ 
             SUB_SVC_ID
        FROM SUB_SVC_PARM ssp
       WHERE PARM_ID = GET_PARM_ID('net_ppv_credit_limit', GET_CLASS_ID('SubSvcSpec'), GET_SVCID('smp_cpe_cas'))
         AND VAL <> '140.00'
         AND EXISTS (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL_INDEX(ss, sub_svc_pk, 4) */ 
                            1
                       FROM SUB_SVC ss
                      WHERE ss.SUB_SVC_ID = ssp.SUB_SVC_ID
                        AND ss.SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID NOT IN (FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'deleted'),
                                                         FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'inactive'),
                                                         FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'add_in_progress'),
                                                         FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'activation_in_progress'),
                                                         FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'courtesy_block_in_progress'),
                                                         FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'mso_block_in_progress'),
                                                         FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'delete_in_progress'),
                                                         FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'deactivation_in_progress'),
                                                         FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'change_in_progress')));
```

I am posting here the original query which is called as a cursor in a procedure.

Explain plan for the query on the domain where it is taking time is --

```
Plan hash value: 4290343623

----------------------------------------------------------------------------           -----------------------------           
  | Id  | Operation                    | Name             | Rows  | Bytes      |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------   ------------------------------
 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                  |  1802K|    56M|       |   528K  (1)|730:11:02 |
 |*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI        |                  |  1802K|    56M|    37M|   528K  (1)|730:11:02 |
 |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | SUB_SVC          |  1763K|    16M|       |   311K  (1)|430:15:33 |
 |   3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SUB_SVC_PARM     |  2394K|    52M|       |   209K  (0)|288:56:00 |
 |*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SUB_SVC_PARM_IX2 |  2394K|       |       |  1519   (0)| 02:05:59 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

 1 - access("SS"."SUB_SVC_ID"="SSP"."SUB_SVC_ID")
 2 - filter("SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','deleted') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','inactive') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','add_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','activation_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','courtesy_block_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','mso_block_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','delete_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','deactivation_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','change_in_progress'))
4 - access("PARM_ID"="GET_PARM_ID"('net_ppv_credit_limit',"GET_CLASS_ID"('SubSvcSpec'),"GET_SV
          CID"('smp_cpe_cas')))
   filter("VAL"<>'140.00')
```

Indexes build on both table are ---

SUB_SVC TABLE

```
index_name      coulmn_name
-----------     ------------
SUB_SVC_PK      sub_svc_id
SUB_SVC_IX4     PARENT_SUB_SVC_ID
SUB_SVC_IX5     EXTERNAL_KEY
SUB_SVC_IX6     SUB_SVC_IX6
```

SUB_SVC_PARM TABLE

```
index_name        coulmn_name
-----------       ------------
SUB_SVC_PARM_PK   SUB_SVC_ID, PARM_ID
SUB_SVC_PARM_IX2  PARM_ID, VAL
```

CREATE TABLE SYNTAX FOR SUB_SVC_PARM TABLE

```
 CREATE TABLE "SMPHOMCM"."SUB_SVC_PARM" 
   (    "SUB_SVC_ID" NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PARM_ID" NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"VAL" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "SUB_SVC_PARM_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SUB_SVC_ID", "PARM_ID")
  USING INDEX)

CREATE TABLE SYNTAX FOR SUB_SVC TABLE

CREATE TABLE "SMPHOMCM"."SUB_SVC" 
   (    "SUB_SVC_ID" NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SUB_ID" NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"START_DT" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"EXTERNAL_KEY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SAMP_VER" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID" NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"CREATED_DTM" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"END_DT" DATE, 
"PURCHASE_DT" DATE, 
"PARENT_SUB_SVC_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
"PRE_STATUS_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
"MODIFIED_DTM" DATE, 
"MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
"SVC_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
 CONSTRAINT "SUB_SVC_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SUB_SVC_ID")
 USING INDEX)
```

Meanwhile i am trying to use WITH clause for the functions calling the where clause however in the procedure there functions are caught in the constant variables which are then used in the query !

My DB is : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Please ask for more information if required. 
Thanks

EDIT: This Procedure is using the query and is not written by me !
      I think this procedure itself needs to be tune other than the query

please suggest

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PPV_CREDIT_LIMIT(p_exid NUMBER)
 IS
 -- Flag 'N' is null

   TYPE tab_sub_svc_id               IS TABLE OF    SUB_SVC_PARM.SUB_SVC_ID%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   rs_sub_svc_id                     tab_sub_svc_id;

   c_class_SubSvcSpec                constant pls_integer := GET_CLASS_ID('SubSvcSpec');
   c_svc_smp_cpe_cas                 constant pls_integer := GET_SVCID('smp_cpe_cas');
   c_parm_net_ppv_credit_limit       constant pls_integer := GET_PARM_ID('net_ppv_credit_limit', c_class_SubSvcSpec, c_svc_smp_cpe_cas);
   c_deleted                         constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'deleted');
   c_inactive                        constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'inactive');
   c_add_in_progress                 constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'add_in_progress');
   c_activation_in_progress          constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'activation_in_progress');
   c_courtesy_block_in_progress      constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'courtesy_block_in_progress');
   c_mso_block_in_progress           constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'mso_block_in_progress');
   c_delete_in_progress              constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'delete_in_progress');
   c_deactivation_in_progress        constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'deactivation_in_progress');
   c_change_in_progress              constant pls_integer := FN_GET_STATUS_ID('SubSvcSpec', 'change_in_progress');
   c_ppv_credit_limit                constant varchar2(6) := '140.00';
   -- Added for net_creditthreshold parm
   c_parm_ppv_credit_threshold       constant pls_integer :=   GET_PARM_ID('net_ppv_creditthreshold', c_class_SubSvcSpec, c_svc_smp_cpe_cas);
   c_ppv_credit_threshold            constant varchar2(6) := '80.00';
   ilimit                            CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 1000;
   iCheck                            CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 10;
   l_total_recs                               PLS_INTEGER;
   l_rec_cnt                                  PLS_INTEGER;
   l_curr_cnt                                 PLS_INTEGER := 0;
   l_batch                                    PLS_INTEGER := 0;
   v_stop_flag                                CHAR(1) := 'N';

   cursor curPPV_CL IS
      SELECT /*+ PARALLEL_INDEX(ssp, sub_svc_parm_ix2, 4) 
                          INDEX(ssp sub_svc_parm_ix2) */ 
             SUB_SVC_ID
        FROM SUB_SVC_PARM ssp
       WHERE PARM_ID = c_parm_net_ppv_credit_limit
         AND VAL <> '140.00'
         AND EXISTS (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL_INDEX(ss, sub_svc_pk, 4) */ 
                            1
                       FROM SUB_SVC ss
                      WHERE ss.SUB_SVC_ID = ssp.SUB_SVC_ID
                        AND ss.SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID NOT IN (c_deleted,
                                                         c_inactive,
                                                         c_add_in_progress,
                                                         c_activation_in_progress,
                                                         c_courtesy_block_in_progress,
                                                         c_mso_block_in_progress,
                                                         c_delete_in_progress,
                                                         c_deactivation_in_progress,
                                                         c_change_in_progress));

BEGIN

   DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_action (NULL);
   DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_module (NULL, NULL);
   DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_client_info (NULL);

   DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_module (module_name => 'Procedure: PPV_CREDIT_LIMIT',
                                 action_name => 'Counting total updatable records');

   SELECT /*+ PARALLEL_INDEX(ssp, sub_svc_parm_ix2, 4) 
                   INDEX(ssp sub_svc_parm_ix2) */ 
      COUNT(SUB_SVC_ID)
 INTO l_total_recs
 FROM SUB_SVC_PARM ssp
WHERE PARM_ID = c_parm_net_ppv_credit_limit
  AND VAL <> '140.00'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL_INDEX(ss, sub_svc_pk, 4) */ 
                     1
                FROM SUB_SVC ss
               WHERE ss.SUB_SVC_ID = ssp.SUB_SVC_ID
                 AND ss.SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID NOT IN (c_deleted,
                                                  c_inactive,
                                                  c_add_in_progress,
                                                  c_activation_in_progress,
                                                  c_courtesy_block_in_progress,
                                                  c_mso_block_in_progress,
                                                  c_delete_in_progress,
                                                  c_deactivation_in_progress,
                                                  c_change_in_progress));

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total records for updating are : ' || l_total_recs);

   OPEN curPPV_CL;

   LOOP
       FETCH curPPV_CL
        BULK COLLECT INTO rs_sub_svc_id limit ilimit;

       l_rec_cnt := rs_sub_svc_id.COUNT;
       l_curr_cnt := l_curr_cnt + l_rec_cnt;

       DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_module (module_name => 'Procedure: PPV_CREDIT_LIMIT',
                                     action_name => 'Updating ' ||    l_curr_cnt || ' of ' || l_total_recs);

       for idx in 1 .. l_rec_cnt
        LOOP 
          UPDATE SUB_SVC_PARM
         SET VAL = c_ppv_credit_limit
       WHERE SUB_SVC_ID = rs_sub_svc_id(idx)
         AND PARM_ID = c_parm_net_ppv_credit_limit;

      UPDATE SUB_SVC_PARM
         SET VAL = c_ppv_credit_threshold
       WHERE SUB_SVC_ID = rs_sub_svc_id(idx)
         AND PARM_ID = c_parm_ppv_credit_threshold;

    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;


   l_batch := l_batch + 1;
   DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_client_info ('BATCH:' || l_batch * ilimit);
   EXIT WHEN l_rec_cnt < ilimit;

   IF   MOD(l_batch, iCheck) = 0
   THEN
        SELECT STOP_FLAG
          INTO v_stop_flag
          FROM DM_PPV_CREDIT_LIMIT
         WHERE EXECUTION_ID = p_exid;
   END IF;

   EXIT WHEN v_stop_flag = 'Y';

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE curPPV_CL;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Have updated records : ' || l_curr_cnt || ' out of total records : ' || l_total_recs  );

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
END PPV_CREDIT_LIMIT;
```

EXPLAIN PLAN AFTER CREATING TWO INDEXES -

```
create index sub_svc_parm_ixpvs on sub_svc_parm (parm_id, val, sub_svc_id) ;

create index sub_svc_ixss on sub_svc (sub_svc_id, sub_svc_status_id) TABLESPACE "SMP_IDX_SUB_SVC" ;


Plan hash value: 176576580

----------------------------------------------------------------------------       --------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    --------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |                    |  1802K|    56M|       | 43296   (1)| 59:49:34 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN        |                    |  1802K|    56M|    37M| 43296   (1)| 59:49:34 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN | SUB_SVC_IXSS       |  1763K|    16M|       | 33679   (1)| 46:32:15 |
|*  3 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| SUB_SVC_PARM_IXPVS |  2308K|    50M|       |  1857   (0)| 02:34:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("SS"."SUB_SVC_ID"="SSP"."SUB_SVC_ID")
   2 - filter("SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','deleted') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','inactive') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','add_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','activation_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','courtesy_block_in_progress') 
          AND "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','mso_block_in_progress') 
          AND "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','delete_in_progress') AND 
          "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','deactivation_in_progress') 
          AND "SS"."SUB_SVC_STATUS_ID"<>"FN_GET_STATUS_ID"('SubSvcSpec','change_in_progress'))
   3 - access("SSP"."PARM_ID"="GET_PARM_ID"('net_ppv_credit_limit',"GET_CLASS_ID"('SubSv
          cSpec'),"GET_SVCID"('smp_cpe_cas')))
   filter("SSP"."VAL"<>'140.00')
```

Comment: It's used in a cursor. Ca you clairfy: when you run your provided query _not_ in a cursor does it take that long?

Comment: I am updating the questio and adding the procedure where this query is being used

Comment: Can you clarify: is it the _procedure_ or the _query_ that takes 4-5 hours? If it's the procedure, then how long does the query take?

Comment: I am execute that query and its running from last 1.30 hours :( and after creating the new indexes on the column check the question for updated explain plan after creating indexes

Comment: First you have to know where exactly those 4-5 hours are spent. https://community.oracle.com/thread/503834?tstart=0

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Your query plan and indexes look reasonable.  That leads one to suspect the function calls.

Your data does not look incredibly big . . . tables with a few million rows.  My suspicion is that these are being called a zillion times.  People who come from more traditional programming languages often think that functions are a great way to program in SQL; unfortunately, they can incur a lot of overhead, because they can prevent the optimizer from doing its work.

So, can you declare the functions to be `DETERMINISTIC`?  That will help the optimizer compile them.  Second, store the values in the `NOT IN` list in a CTE, or better yet, in a temporary table with an index.  Do something similar for the  `PARM_ID` value.

Comment: i can replace these functions with with SQL queries also if i use these functions in with clause then will it be helpful here.  yeah as these query are not written by me i always tried to avoid function calls in SQL. And one more question how do come to know about the table size by looking at the Explain plan !

Comment: @mradul . . . The "Rows" column is an indication of the expected data volume.

Comment: If i am not wrong but these rows are the rows which are returned by each operations !

Answer (score -1):

As it is only the `SUB_SVC_ID` you want to return, you can get it from SUB_SVC_PARM where the SUB_SVC matches or from SUB_SVC where the SUB_SVC_PARM or from the join of the two or from the intersection. The optimizer should get to the same execution plan in any case, but you can still try:

Your query (with IN instead of EXISTS, which doesn't change anything but enhance readability):

```
select sub_svc_id
from sub_svc_parm
where parm_id = get_parm_id(...)
and val <> '140.00'
and sub_svc_id in (select sub_svc_id from sub_svc where sub_svc_status_id not in (...));
```

Alternative #1:

```
select sub_svc_id
from sub_svc
where sub_svc_status_id not in (...)
and sub_svc_id in 
  (select * from sub_svc_parm where parm_id = get_parm_id(...) and val <> '140.00');
```

Alternative #2:

```
select sub_svc_id
from sub_svc ss
join sub_svc_parm ssp using (sub_svc_id)
where ss.sub_svc_status_id not in (...)
and ssp.parm_id = get_parm_id(...) 
and ssp.val <> '140.00');
```

Alternative #3:

```
select sub_svc_id
from sub_svc_parm
where parm_id = get_parm_id(...)
and val <> '140.00'
intersect
select sub_svc_id 
from sub_svc 
where sub_svc_status_id not in (...));
```

In any case, indexes should ideally be: `sub_svc_parm(parm_id, val, sub_svc_id)` and `sub_svc(sub_svc_status_id, sub_svc_id)`. Adding these may already speed up the existing query.

I'd try it without any hints first to see what execution plans the optimizer produces for these queries. Then you may want to add parallelization hints again.

Comment: I tried all the alternatives you provided but none of them help :( all gives the same cost however the intersect option increase the cost. i think i need to build an index on sub-svc_status_id column and remove the function calling from the where clause !!

Comment: Okay, as mentioned, the optimizer *should* produce the same plan, so I am not surprised it didn't help. It was just a slight chance, nothing more. But did you add the two indexes? These are very likely to speed up the query.

Comment: yeah i was thinking of same i need to take permission for this as it is a onsite domain and the explain plan are same even when i changed the functions with simple SQL query and for all the alternatives that you provided !\

Comment: Also i want to know do i need to add index for both column or is it OK if i add only for sub_svc_status_id as sub_svc_id is already a primary_key

Comment: I added column on sub_svc_statis_id column and it reduces the cost to 505K :)